# TypeScript: error TS2345: Argument of type 'JQueryXHR' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<any>'

Tags: jquery, typescript, promise, observable

The following example code snippet is presented in a tutorial on how to perform a JQuery getJSON() call and then convert the JQueryXHR result to a Promise, which is then converted to an Observable.

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control">
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  example(searchTerm: string) {
    let url: string =
      "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=artist&q=" + searchTerm;
    let jqueryXhr: JQueryXHR = $.getJSON(url);
    let observable: Observable<any> = Observable.fromPromise(jqueryXhr);
  }
}
```

This example does work at runtime, but the tsc compiler throws the following error:

```
app/app.component.ts(28,61): error TS2345: Argument of type 'JQueryXHR' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<any>'.
  Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
```

Is there a clean way to cast or convert a JQueryXHR object to a Promise, or another type, that can be converted to an Observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a clean way to cast or convert a JQueryXHR object to a Promise?

You're looking for [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) which does exactly that.

However, your current code should work already if only the types would be more precise. `fromPromise` should not require a `Promise` but only a `Thenable`, and `JQueryXHR` should implement the `Thenable` interface.

Comment: Per the error, the types of property "then" are incompatible, resulting in an error using an implicit or explicit cast.  But, using your suggestion of Promise.resolve() worked, and this satisfied the compiler.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's the difference between thenables and promises - in the latter, the return values of the `then` method and its callbacks matter.

Answer (score 2):

Answer (thanks @Bergi):

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control">
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  example(searchTerm: string) {
    let url: string =
      "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=artist&q=" + searchTerm;
    let jqueryXhr: JQueryXHR = $.getJSON(url);
    let promise: Promise<any> = Promise.resolve(jqueryXhr);
    let observable = Observable.fromPromise(promise);
  }
}
```